# SFML undefined reference to impl

Tags: c++, windows, sfml

I'm getting the following undefined references when using SFML for GCC 4.7 MinGW (DW2) - 32 bits:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -I$(SFML_INCLUDE) -o pong main.o

main.o:main.cpp: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6StringC1EPKc
RKSt6locale'
main.o:main.cpp: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf9VideoModeC1E
jjj'
main.o:main.cpp: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindo
wC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE'
main.o:main.cpp: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf11CircleShape
C1Efj'
....
....
....
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

There are many more than this. This is how I am linking:

```
LIBRARIES = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lglew32
g++ -c include/main.cpp -L/lib  $(LIBRARIES)
```

I'm on Windows. How do I get rid of these undefined references?

EDIT: This is the program:

```
#define SFML_STATIC

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you've defined all your pointers, functions, etc?

Comment: @zyboxinternational Yeah. The only thing inside `main.cpp` is the example program that SFML provides.

Comment: I think you have to add -lsfml-system for the core features. (It's missing in your linking command)

Comment: I balanced downvote -.-

Comment: @Kapichu Adding it didn't help. Maybe the order is wrong?

Comment: In [this page](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-linux.php) (I suggest you to look at it) the order in the linking command is `-lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`. Did you do that?

Comment: @Kapichu `-lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lglew32`

Comment: Can you provide us your source code? And, by the way, why is your main.cpp located at include/ ?

Comment: @Kapichu It's just a directory I made called `include/` to hold all the cpp files. And you can see the source code above.

Comment: Have you tried omitting `#define SFML_STATIC` ?

Comment: @Kapichu Yes, same errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have compiling and linking mixed up.  This is linking:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -I$(SFML_INCLUDE) -o pong main.o
```

And this is compiling:

```
g++ -c include/main.cpp -L/lib  $(LIBRARIES)
```

The linking, not the compiling, needs the `$(LIBRARIES)` variable and the `-L` option.

```
g++ main.o -o pong -L/lib $(LIBRARIES)
```

And the compiling needs the `-std=c++11` and the `-Wall` and the `-I`.

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -c -I$(SFML_INCLUDE) include/main.cpp
```

Comment: That gets rid of the original errors. But now I'm getting "cannot find `-lsfml-windows/graphics/system`"

Comment: Did you actually follow the tutorial (http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-linux.php) ? (Since you are using GNU tools, it should help, though intended to be for linux)

Comment: @user2030677: Come to think of it, what is `-L/lib` supposed to be? Are the libraries in a subdirectory of the working directory named "lib"? Try `-L"./lib"`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, `/lib` is a subdirectory where I copied all the DLL files from the SFML `bin` directory. When I do `-L"./lib"` it still gives the same error though.

Comment: @user2030677: Where are the `.a` files?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I'm not using `a` files, those are in the `lib` directory of the original SFML directory. I'm using the `.dll` files.

Comment: @user2030677: You have to use the `.a` files. Even if you are using the `.dll` files. That's where the code is which allows your program to link with the dll files at runtime.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Okay. I use that and it compiles fine. Thanks! But can you also help me with this last thing: when I run the `.exe` file it brings up an error box that says: "This application failed to start because `sfml-graphics-2.dll` was noot found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem." Note that I got rid of `-L"./lib"` and replaced it with `-L$(PATH_TO_A_FILES)`

Comment: @user2030677: Place your dll files in the same directory as your exe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60342/discussion-between-user2030677-and-benjamin-lindley).