# (SFML, Code::Blocks) "undefined reference to (...)" error upon Texture.importFromFile(...)

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I decided to try out what is depicted in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zH_omFPqMO4) (building a Tetris game with C++) (I
mention the video for reference purposes).

I have Code::Blocks 17.12. I installed SFML (GCC 4.9.2 TDM (SJLJ) - 32-bit) from [their download page](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.4.2/) and since "the compilers have to match 100%" I also installed TDM 4.9.2 (32-bit) from the link also provided on their download page (not before having run into errors from overlooking this detail to some extent), and set it as my compiler in Code::Blocks.

I followed the tutorial on SFML page. I ran into a couple errors but managed to fix them (such as the one mentioned in the previous parenthetical remark... among others). Everything went fine so I moved on to the code as shown in the YouTube video. At the point where the code is

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <time.h>
using namespace sf;

int main()
{
   RenderWindow window(VideoMode(320, 480), "window");

   Texture t;
   t.loadFromFile("images/tiles.png");

   Sprite s(t);

   while (window.isOpen())
   {
       Event e;
       while (window.pollEvent(e))
       {
           if (e.type == Event::Closed)
           window.close();
       }
       window.clear(Color::White);
       window.display();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

(for the record) I get the error

```
||=== Build: Release in Tetris (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x24c)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf7Texture12loadFromFileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traits
IcESaIcEEERKNS_4RectIiEE'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s)) ===|
```

This is my problem.

[An answer to a related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32441564/9447177) suggests something that I understand as "you have to use in C::B the same
compiler as the one which was used to compile SMFL". However I think I have ensured that.

[Another related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594660/sfml-undefined-reference-to-impl) I read but cannot understand anything. I am a total
noob to C/C++ and can't do much more than dilligently, thoughtlessly following
the directions as for example were provided in the tutorial in the SFML site... so if anyone can help me, I'd appreciate it -- could it be made to work or will I have to build SFML myself?

EDIT: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcAjv.jpg) are screenshots for my linker settings.

Comment: Likely you didn't properly link the SFML library. There should be a .a file included with the SFML download. Go to your project and add this .a file into your linker settings

Comment: A section on the SFML tutorial says: "The next step is to link your application to the SFML libraries (.a files) that your code will need. SFML is made of 5 modules (system, window, graphics, network and audio), and there's one library for each of them.
Libraries must be added to the "Link libraries" list in the project's build options, under the "Linker settings" tab. Add all the SFML libraries that you need, for example "sfml-graphics", "sfml-window" and "sfml-system" (the "lib" prefix and the ".a" extension must be omitted)." **Would this be the part you believe I got wrong?**

Comment: [Here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-cb.php)'s the link for the aforementioned tutorial. I believe that I followed that part exactly as described in that section of the tutorial (I can elaborate on this claim).

Comment: Yes I believe that's the part you got wrong. Update your question with your linker settings attached

Comment: OK. It's at the end of the post.

Answer (score 0):

With [this link](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-cb.php) you provided in the comments, it looks like your linker settings should be the following:

```
sfml-window-s
sfml-system-s
opengl32
freetype
jpeg
```

I had an issue similar to this when I was trying to use SFML, and the linker settings in the correct order was the issue.

Comment: Ah, I see. I am going to try that and report back. I kind of skimmed over that section of the tutorial because I believed it pertained exclusively to static linking (the "-s" postfix suggests so...)

Comment: Well. I tried it, updated my linker settings and defined the SFML_STATIC macro in the preprocessor options as specified in the tutorial and I still get errors... `obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc5)  ||  undefined reference to \`_imp___ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale'|`... a bunch of those